# Code after 'return' will never be executed

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, url, avaudioplayer

I'm in my first week of coding. 
So far the youtube tutorial app I am making in swift is going perfectly apart from the above error message. Here is the code. I have rewritten this twice now exactly as they specify.
I am trying to set up sounds to play with the card game we are making, the sounds play when cards are shuffled, turned around, matched or incorrectly matched. 
The error message is shown for "let soundURL" line of code, "Code after 'return' will never be executed".
Please help?

```
class SoundManager {

   static var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    enum SoundEffect {

        case flip
        case shuffle
        case match
        case nomatch

    }

   static func playSound(_ effect:SoundEffect) {

        var soundFilename = ""

        // Determine which sound effect we want to play
        //and set the appropriate file name

        switch effect {

        case .flip:
            soundFilename = "cardflip"

        case .shuffle:
            soundFilename = "cardflip"

        case .match:
            soundFilename = "dingcorrect"

        case.nomatch:
            soundFilename = "dingwrong"

        }
        // Get the path to the sound file inside the bundle
        let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundFilename, ofType: "wav")

        guard bundlePath != nil else {
            print("Couldn't find sound file \(soundFilename) in the bundle")
            return



            // Create a URL object from this string path
            let soundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePath!)


            do {
                // Create audio player object
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)

                // Play the sound
                audioPlayer?.play()
            }
            catch {
                // Could'nt create audio player object, log the error
                print("Could'nt create the audio player object for sound file \(soundFilename)")
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you have the `return` keyword (presumably above the first line of code you provided). As the error suggests, once the return keyword appears, the application will exit that method, so any code below that `return` keyword won't execute. Can you include the code that has this `return` keyword?

Comment: Hey David I added the code above, copying it in here looked awful and unreadable. 
I wonder why my tutorial told me to add return when anything after it wont work.

Comment: Look at `guard bundlePath != nil else {`, all the code below `return` will not be executed.  I think you need to put a `}` after `return`, but you will probably need to remove one as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want your code to look something like this:

```swift
// Get the path to the sound file inside the bundle
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundFilename, ofType: "wav")

guard bundlePath != nil else {
    print("Couldn't find sound file \(soundFilename) in the bundle")
    return
}

// Create a URL object from this string path
let soundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePath!)


do {
    // Create audio player object
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)

    // Play the sound
    audioPlayer?.play()
}
catch {
    // Could'nt create audio player object, log the error
    print("Could'nt create the audio player object for sound file \(soundFilename)")
}
```

If there is a `guard` statement with `return` inside its brackets, you do not want to put any code beneath the `return` and within the same brackets. None of the code below the `return` will execute. In my example, the following code is **outside** of the brackets, meaning it will execute so long as there is a value for `bundlePath`.

Comment: I copied the whole soundManager swift file above. 
I just used your code and it worked like a charm! 
Everything works as it should, now I just need to spend some time understanding what you did. 
I can't thank you enough David.

Comment: Glad it worked :) you should read a bit about optional handling https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/optionals-in-swift-2b141f12f870 or `guard`/`return` statements in general https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Code after 'return' will never be executed



var soundFilename = ""

// Determine which sound effect we want to play
//and set the appropriate file name

switch effect {

case .flip:
    soundFilename = "cardflip"

case .shuffle:
    soundFilename = "cardflip"

case .match:
    soundFilename = "dingcorrect"

case.nomatch:
    soundFilename = "dingwrong"

}
// Get the path to the sound file inside the bundle
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundFilename, ofType: "wav")

guard bundlePath != nil else {
    print("Couldn't find sound file \(soundFilename) in the bundle")
    return

   }

    // Create a URL object from this string path
    let soundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePath!)


    do {
        // Create audio player object
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)

        // Play the sound
        audioPlayer?.play()
    }
    catch {
        // Could'nt create audio player object, log the error
        print("Could'nt create the audio player object for sound file \(soundFilename)")
    }
// }

}
```

I believe that you have misunderstood the guard syntax as it will execute the code when the condition is correct and will fall in else part when the condition is false. So therefore it will use return in else with no other code , So that the method will be terminated gracefully without giving any crash.

The return keyword is used to return something with the method execution or to exit from the method.

So you need to close the else part with “}” and remove one below catch block. Hope this helps.